# Не работает npm run dev

Tags: node.js, express

Делаю проект. На самом начальном этапе выдает ошибки на `npm run dev. Полный файл package.json:`

```
    {
  "name": "devcamper_api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Devcamper backend API",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server",
    "dev": "nodemon server"
  },
  "author": "Nadezda",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Ошибка:

> The system cannot find the path specified.
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895   throw err;   ^
> Error: Cannot find module 'E:\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'

Переустанавливала `node_module, package.json` - ничего не помогает.

Comment: запусти вот так -- `npm dev` и должно работать

Comment: @Air не работает, пишет не верная команда

Comment: Модуль nodemon точно у вас есть? Ведь в логе именно его отсутствие отмечено.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

Comment: `nodemon` установлен глобально или локально?

Comment: выложи сюда весь `package.json`

Comment: @Air, добавила полный файл package.json.

Comment: Попробуйте глобально установить nodemon